# Using autolayouts programatically How to set dynamic height for UItableView cell and UItextView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios i have set here UItextview on UItableview cell but according to my requirement i have to set UItextview and UItableview cell height dynamically based on text data and my code is below according to my code 6 plus screen is coming like first image[image]

### MY code is below:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    UITableView * MaintableView;
    NSArray * mainArray;
    NSArray * aboutArray;
    NSArray * formulaArray;

    //UItextFields
    UITextField * firstName;
    UITextField * secondName;
    UITextField * thirdName;
    UITextField * fourthName;
    UITextField * fifthName;
    UITextField * sixthName;
    UITextField * seventhName;
    UITextField * eightName;
    UITextField * ninthName;

    //UILabels
    UILabel * firstLabel;
    UILabel * secondLabel;
    UILabel * thirdLabel;
    UILabel * fourthLabel;
    UILabel * fifthLabel;
    UILabel * sixthLabel;
    UILabel * seventhLabel;
    UILabel * eigthLabel;
    UILabel * ninthLabel;

    //UItextViews
    UITextView * formulaText;
    UITextView * aboutText;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mainArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];

    aboutArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    formulaArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    aboutArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"The server encountered an error while trying to process the request. You could retry the same request following the requirements listed in Timeout (see row above). If the error persists, please report the problem in the android-gcm group.The server encountered an error while trying to process the request. You could retry",@"The server encountered an error while trying to process the request. You could retry the same request following the requirements listed in Timeout (see row above). If the error persists, please report the problem in the android-gcm group.The server encountered an error while trying to process the request. You could retry the same request following the requirements listed in Timeout (see row above). If the error persists, please report the problem in the android-gcm group.The server encountered an error while trying to process the request. You could retry the same request following the requirements listed in Timeout (see row above). If the error persists, please report the problem in the android-gcm group.",nil];

    formulaArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry,Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry,Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry,Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry,finally",nil];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    MaintableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    MaintableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    MaintableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    MaintableView.dataSource=self;
    MaintableView.delegate=self;
    MaintableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [MaintableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    MaintableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:MaintableView];

    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(MaintableView);

    NSArray * horizentalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[MaintableView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    NSArray * verticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[MaintableView]-50-|"options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    [self.view addConstraints:horizentalConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraint];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [mainArray count];
}

- (UIFont *)fontForCell
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if([indexPath section] == 0)
    {

        //Labels adding on cell

        firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        firstLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        firstLabel.text = @"label1";
        firstLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        firstLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:firstLabel];

        secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        secondLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        secondLabel.text = @"label2";
        secondLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];

        //TextFields adding on cell
        firstName = [[UITextField alloc]init];
        firstName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        firstName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        firstName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        firstName.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:firstName];

        secondName = [[UITextField alloc]init];
        secondName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        secondName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        secondName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        secondName.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:secondName];


        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(firstLabel,secondLabel,firstName,secondName);


        //Applying autolayouts for Labels
        NSArray * firstLabelH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[firstLabel]-10-|"
                                                                                  options:0
                                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views];

        NSArray * secondLabelH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[secondLabel]-10-|"
                                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views];

        NSArray * firstLabelV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-7-[firstLabel(25)]-|"options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

        NSArray * secondLabelV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-90-[secondLabel(25)]-|"options:0 metrics:nil views:views];


        //Applying autolayouts for textfields
        NSArray * firstNameH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[firstName]-10-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views];

        NSArray * secondNameH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[secondName]-10-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views];

        NSArray * firstNameV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-35-[firstName(30)]-|"options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

        NSArray * secondNameV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-117-[secondName(30)]-|"options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

        //Adding labels
         [cell.contentView addConstraints:firstLabelH];
         [cell.contentView addConstraints:firstLabelV];
         [cell.contentView addConstraints:secondLabelH];
         [cell.contentView addConstraints:secondLabelV];

        //Adding textFields
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:firstNameH];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:firstNameV];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:secondNameH];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:secondNameV];
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {

        formulaText = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        formulaText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        formulaText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        formulaText.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        formulaText.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:formulaText];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(formulaText);

        NSArray * formulaH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[formulaText]-10-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views];

        NSArray * formulaV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[formulaText]-5-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaH];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaV];


        formulaText.text = [formulaArray objectAtIndex:0];
        formulaText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0];

    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        aboutText = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        aboutText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        aboutText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        aboutText.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        aboutText.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aboutText];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(aboutText);

        NSArray * formulaH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[aboutText]-10-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        NSArray * formulaV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[aboutText]-5-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaH];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaV];

        aboutText.text = [aboutArray objectAtIndex:0];
        aboutText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0];

    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //return 200;

    if([indexPath section] == 0)
    {
        return  200;
    }

    else if([indexPath section] == 1)
    {
        NSString *cellText = [formulaArray objectAtIndex:0];
        UIFont *cellFont = [self fontForCell];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        return labelSize.height + 20;
    }

    else
    {
        NSString *cellText = [aboutArray objectAtIndex:0];
        UIFont *cellFont = [self fontForCell];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        return labelSize.height + 20;
    }

}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                 CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30.0)];
    sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

    UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [headerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20.0]];
    headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [sectionHeaderView addSubview:headerLabel];

    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerLabel);

    NSArray * horizentalConstraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[headerLabel]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    NSArray * verticalConstraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[headerLabel(25)]-|"options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    [sectionHeaderView addConstraints:horizentalConstraint1];
    [sectionHeaderView addConstraints:verticalConstraint1];

    switch (section) {

        case 0:
            headerLabel.text = @"Europe";
            return sectionHeaderView;
            break;

        case 1:
            headerLabel.text = @"Asia";
            return sectionHeaderView;
            break;

        case 2:
            headerLabel.text = @"South America";
            return sectionHeaderView;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return sectionHeaderView;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView * myImage = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
    myImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return myImage;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50.0f;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

@end
```

But i want deduct that empty space even in 6 plus also as like second image please help me some one [image]

Answer (score 0):

Create your `UITableViewCell` - for instance `ContinentUITableViewCell` with xib. set your elements there and set autolayout as you wish. In your `UITableView` register it, and set reuse identifier.

Next thing is to replace your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method with:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

also, in your `viewDidLoad` set `self.tableView.estimatedHeight` to average height ( for instance 200 ).

Comment: thanks a lot now my requirement is working with your solution

Comment: Great, please accept my answer or provide your own so this question can be closed :)